# What is the universal emblem that represents space exploration?

Tags: history, mission-patch

I am interested if there is an official emblem that represents space exploration worldwide?

Are there any small pictures that everyone would recognize or associate to space exploration?

I had more body to this but made it off topic, so I moved most of it here.
[Why doesn't Space.SE have an icon?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1210/why-doesnt-space-se-have-an-icon)

Comment: I looked here but don't see anything: https://www.iso.org/files/live/sites/isoorg/files/archive/pdf/en/graphical-symbols_booklet.pdf or here either http://mentalfloss.com/article/30552/everywhere-sign-brief-history-international-symbolsrganicMarble I love old, yellowed paperbacks, even images of them! This will be fun.

Comment: @uhoh I answered it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After long thought a rocket ship with a window would be recognized as a symbol of space exploration in most languages.

[image]

[image]
https://sockrotation.com/2016/07/07/retro-space-design-cosmonaut-mission-patches/

[image]
The first variant of the patch of the Russian-American-Brazilian crew of the Soyuz TMA-8 spaceship.
https://sockrotation.com/2016/07/07/retro-space-design-cosmonaut-mission-patches/

From comments:
[image]
https://news.sky.com/story/spacex-boss-elon-musk-reveals-new-rocket-prototype-starship-11607041

Comment: Agreed, but: If your rocket ship looks like this, you won't go to space today.

Comment: @asdfex *cough* - https://news.sky.com/story/spacex-boss-elon-musk-reveals-new-rocket-prototype-starship-11607041